# Crontab failing shell script if statement

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a shell script which executes a python program by first checking if it is running

However, the problem is that it seems to fail the first block of the if statement. The shell script does work manually

This is what my shell script looks like:

```
PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

if [ $(/bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py") ]; then
    echo "script running"
else
    echo "script not running"
    exec tmux new-session -d \; send-keys "source activate python310 && cd /home/putsncalls23/directory/ && python miner_nbeats.py" Enter
fi
```

And this is what i have in my `/etc/crontab` file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

*/5 *    * * *  root    putsncalls23 -l /home/putsncalls23/run_script.sh
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here ?

**EDIT:**

After doing more googling, I also saw something like this

```
PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
if /bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py" >/dev/null; then
    echo "script running"
else
    echo "script not running"
    tmux new-session \; send-keys "source activate python310 && cd /home/putsncalls23/directory && python miner_nbeats.py$
fi
```

I just wanted to clarify if the new shell script works and what the effect of `/bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py" >/dev/null` does. For example, after executing miner_beats.py, it seems to output:

```
21080
21128
```

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to do a `cd` to a file.  That command is not right.

Comment: This approach is just bound to be unreliable and to fail in all sorts of unexpected ways. Use `systemd` units (`.service` and `.timer`) to properly track and maintain the lifecycle of processes, to restart them as needed or run them periodically, to handle their dependencies on the rest of the system (and vice versa), to manage their logs and outputs, to sandbox them etc. etc. `cron` is a broken non-solution and better avoided. Decisions based on the list of processes at a given point in time are inherently unreliable, if not unsafe, etc. `systemd` FTW.

Comment: `if [ $(cmd) ]` is almost certainly wrong.  (I'm hedging my bets by saying "almost".  In fact this is always wrong.)  Consider what it means.  It will execute `cmd` and pass its output as arguments to `[`.  But `[` is very fickle, and most likely the output of `cmd` will just be invalid arguments and `[` will complain with an error.  Or, perhaps `cmd` outputs a single string with no whitespace, and `[` will return successfully because that string is non-empty.  But if you want to test that the output of `cmd` is non-empty, this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: edited the cd part so that its a python instead

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest a couple of changes.  First, instead of substituting the stdout from that process, just check the exit code.  Next, your "cd" command was trying to cd to a file.  I think you want something like this:

```
PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

if /bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py" > /dev/null; then
    echo "script not running"
    exec tmux new-session -d \; send-keys "source activate python310 && cd /home/putsncalls23 && ./miner_nbeats.py" Enter
else
    echo "script running"
fi
```

Comment: Excellent point.  I will update.

Comment: sorry about that, i actually updated, what i meant to type was to run cd ... && python miner_nbeats.py. 

I also changed it to if /bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py" and it seems to work. Not too sure why `if [ $(/bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py") ]` doesnt work though, is it because its possible to have multiple processes of the file running ?

Comment: Actually, my new edited bash file which seems to work is actually different from yours, just wanted to clarify too

Comment: Your edited script is only trivially different from mine.  You really should mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: actually, im running into another error afterwards where the python program might get killed but  `/bin/pgrep -f "miner_nbeats.py"` still detects that the script is running. Im guessing that its because of the shell script. 

Do you have any ideas for this ?

Comment: The process continues to be listed while it is being cleaned up.  Use `pgrep -af miner_nbeats.py >> /tmp/log` if you want to keep a record of what pgrep actually found.